# HMAC_Init crashes while calculating HMAC-SHA1

Tags: c++, openssl

Here is my code:

```
int function(const char * buffer,size_t len,unsigned char * value)  
{   

char* user = "username";  
char*password = "password";  
size_t text_len = strlen(user) + strlen(password) + 2;  
  unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*)calloc(1,16);  
  unsigned char* text= (unsigned char *)calloc(1,text_len);  

  snprintf((char*)text, text_len, "%s:%s",user,password );  

MD5(text, text_len-1, key)

  HMAC_CTX *ctx = NULL;  
  unsigned int md_len = 20;  
  ctx = (HMAC_CTX*) calloc(1,sizeof(HMAC_CTX));  
  if(ctx == NULL){return -1;}

  HMAC_CTX_init(ctx);  
  `HMAC_Init(ctx, key, 16, EVP_sha1());`  //crashing everytime, saying heap corruption
  HMAC_Update(ctx, buffer, len);  
  HMAC_Final(ctx, value, &md_len);   

  HMAC_CTX_cleanup(ctx);  
return 0;  
}
```

I am using openssl 0.9.8.c. If anyone faced this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html) HMAC_Init is deprecated. Might be worth trying HMAC_Init_ex.